# Simple HTML DOM Not Finding DIV

Tags: php, html, dom

I have code trying to extract the Event SKU from the Robot Events Page, [here is an example](http://www.robotevents.com/robot-competitions/archived-seasons/vrc/vrc-season-2013-2014/re-vrc-13-1051.html). The code that I am using dosn't find any of the SKU on the page. The SKU is on line 411, with a div of the class "product-sku". My code doesn't event find the Div on the page and just downloads all the events. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
if(!$events)
{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
while($event = mysqli_fetch_row($events))
{
    $htmldown = file_get_html($event[4]);
    $html->load($htmldown);
    echo "Downloaded";
    foreach ($html->find('div[class=product-sku]') as $row) {
       $sku = $row->plaintext;
       echo $sku;
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me fix my code?

Comment: What is the value of the variable `$htmldown` after the _load_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is used DOMDocument php class. It works successfully for below sample HTML. Please try this code.

```
// new dom object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// HTML string
$html_string = '<html>
                    <body>  
                          <div class="product-sku1" name="div_name">The this the div content product-sku</div>
                          <div class="product-sku2" name="div_name">The this the div content product-sku</div>
                          <div class="product-sku" name="div_name">The this the div content product-sku</div>
                    </body>
                </html>';

//load the html
$html = $dom->loadHTML($html_string);

//discard white space 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;

//the table by its tag name
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

// loop over the all DIVs
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($div->attributes as $attribute){
            if($attribute->name === 'class' && $attribute->value == 'product-sku'){
                // Peri DIV class name and content
                echo 'DIV Class Name: '.$attribute->value.PHP_EOL;
                echo 'DIV Content: '.$div->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex (regular expression) to accomplish pulling skus out.

The regex:

`preg_match('~<div class="product-sku"><b>Event Code:</b>(.*?)</div>~',$html,$matches);`

See [php regex docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

New code:

```
<?php
if(!$events)
{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
while($event = mysqli_fetch_row($events))
{
    $htmldown = curl_init($event[4]);
    curl_setopt($htmldown, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html=curl_exec($htmldown);
    curl_close($htmldown)
    echo "Downloaded";
    
    preg_match('~<div class="product-sku"><b>Event Code:</b>(.*?)</div>~',$html,$matches);
    

    foreach ($matches as $row) {
       echo $row;
    }
}
?>
```

And actually in this case (using that webpage) being that there is only one sku...

instead of:

```
foreach ($matches as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

You could just use: `echo $matches[1];` (The reason for array index 1 is because the whole regex pattern plus the sku will be in $matches[0] but just the subgroup containing the sku is in $matches[1].)

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
if(!$events)
{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
while($event = mysqli_fetch_row($events))
{
    $htmldown = str_get_html($event[4]);
    echo "Downloaded";
    foreach ($htmldown->find('div[class=product-sku]') as $row) {
        $sku = $row->plaintext;
        echo $sku;
    }
}
```

and if class "product-sku" is only for div's then you can use

```
 $htmldown->find('.product-sku')
```